# aws cli put-record for Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to write some data to AWS Kinesis with the CLI, but this isn't working:

```
aws kinesis put-record --stream-name my-stream-name --data Data=jose|12
```

I am getting a "bash: 12: command not found" error.

`aws kinesis put-record help` works so I don't understand the error.

I'm following [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kinesis/put-record.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wrap your data with single quotes:

```
--data 'Data=jose|12'
```

otherwise bash will try to pipe the output of `aws kinesis put-record --stream-name my-stream-name --data Data=jose` to a program called `12`, which does not exist.

You will also need to add the `--partition-key` argument, which you can randomly generate using `` --partition-key `uuidgen` ``.
The whole command will be:

```
aws kinesis put-record --stream-name my-stream-name --data 'Data=jose|12' --partition-key `uuidgen`
```

Comment: with `aws-cli/2.4.15 Python/3.8.8 Linux/5.13.0-27-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off` I see errors                                                                                           `aws kinesis put-record --stream-name LogsToS3BucketDataStream --data 'Data=jose|12' --partition-key `uuidgen`

Invalid base64: "Data=jose|12"`